# AngularJS - Share scope value between controllers

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a textarea in my HTML like this:

```
<textarea ng-model="commentBox"></textarea>
```

To access this i simply use "$scope.commentBox" in my controller. But my question is, how do i access the same commentBox within a different controller?

I do have a factory/service setup for this purpose, but i cant figure out how to get the commentBox value in there, for my other controller to use it.

In my factory i have an object `var saved = {}` and I want to add a property called "comment", with the value of whatever is inside the textarea. Like this `saved.comment = commentbox` And then access that value from the other controller.

I'm still new at Angular and tried to send the scope information in a parameter to the facory.

```
var saved = {};

factory.addComment = function (commentbox) {
  saved.comment = commentbox
}
```

Then have my controller send the scope information on a button click,

```
$scope.testFunction = function () {
  myFactory.addComment($scope.commentBox);
}
```

But yeah, that did not work out.

Note that i need this to work within the factory, and not by using another ng-controller in the HTML.

Comment: Is there any reason you couldn't do ng-Change=factoryProduct.addComment(commentBox), where the factoryProduct is the instance that the Controller has created from the Factory? I assume when you say you're using Factories you mean something like this http://www.sitepoint.com/tidy-angular-controllers-factories-services/

Comment: Not familiar with ng-change, never used it. But i have a route that controlls which controllers to be used on what html. And i have ng-model on page 1, which i need to get the value of on my page 2. And to do so, im trying to put that value from controller 1 into the factory, so controller 2 can access it.

Comment: I think you just need something like ng-change="vm.addComment(commentBox)", where vm.addComment does something like yourService.setCurrentComment(newValue).

Answer (score 1):

You need to return your saved var in your factory

```
var saved = {}; 


factory.addComment = function (commentbox) {
  saved.comment = commentbox
}

return saved
```

Here there is an example using a service

```
app.service('fakeService', function() {
  var savedData = {};

  var addComment = function(newComment) {
      savedData.commnet = newComment;
  };

  var getComment = function(){
      return savedData.comment;
  };

  return {
    addComment: addComment,
    getComment: getComment
  };

});
```

To inject a factory/service in your controller

```
app.controller('fakeController', ['$scope','yourFactory',function ($scope, yourFactory) {

   console.log(yourFactory.comment) // here you should log saved comment

}])
```

Then in your controller, you can inject the factory/service and access to saved data.  But remember, is your refresh your page,  data will be lost, so, to avoid that, you should persist data on your DB.

Comment: I do return the saved variable and everything else that needs to be returned. I just dont know how to add the scope value into the factory, so that my other controllers can access it.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, my factory is already injected in the controllers. I made a simple jsfiddle to narrow down my problem. http://jsfiddle.net/aw5p5hyr/

How do MyCtrl2 get the value of commentBox (like in MyCtrl1), using a factory?

Comment: Where are you using MyCtrl2 in your fiddle? And where are you defining or using your service?

Comment: @qua1ity I think you need add things to your fiddle.